# Strange Visual Studio 2010 crash in very simple project containing unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, crash

I've found surprisingly simple way to crash **Visual Studio 2010** using auto generating *Unit Tests*.

This is the way I made it: `File` => `New Project` => `Class Library` *[.NET Framework 4]*. 
This is complete source code of the program (15 lines of **C#** code):

```cs
namespace UnitTestsCrash
{
    class ClassA<T>
    {
        private T a;
    }

    class ClassB : ClassA<ClassB>
    {
        private void FooA()
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`Build it` and than click `Right Mouse Button` inside `ClassB` body => `Create Unit Tests...` => `OK` => `Create` => `Yes`. The result is *Visual Studio **crashing*** ([screenshot](http://oi50.tinypic.com/2z4bade.jpg))!

I discovered this odd crash in more complex solution. I extracted this problem from bigger project and simplified to above sample. 
I'm not quite sure if it's *Visual Studio 2010* fault or mine. Please verify and explain if it's my fault.

I need to test big class which inherits in similar manner as `ClassB` but I can't do it in automated way.

Comment: Man, you've just broke my VS2010 )) It's interesting that class library is actually compiled, but compiling test project throws error saying that there is a problem in `clr.dll`.

Comment: I know. I was debugging *VS2010* in another *VS2010* instance and AFAIR there is *overflow* in *clr.dll*.

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with private accessors. Actually your case just proved me one more time that accessors are just pure evil. They force to recompile all referenced projects each time the test case is changed. Also, according to this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/01/18/publicize-and-code-generation-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx, VS team test stopped support of accessors in VS2010, so it's no surprise that there are problems in accessors. Use reflection!

VS2012 crashes too. So they didn't change anything in accessors, more than that accessors are deprecated in VS2012.

Comment: Is there any way to automate generating unit tests then? In reference to link you've posted, there is written that *However, there is not any good replacement for Code Generation for the new features added by the lanugage teams.* It's quite disappointing...

Comment: @patryk.beza What is code generation actually? I maybe wrong because I rarely use test code generation, but generation actually just creates some simple stub containing `test context` and commented `CleanUp/Initialize` methods, plus method with accessor and invoking private method. simply speaking, in my test framework I have base class containing test context and `TestInitialize/CleanUp` methods, then I inherit from it and work with reflection. Somehow, my base class is the substitution of code generated class.

Comment: Generating *Unit Tests* stubs with auto-comments and attributes was very nice idea... But as I mentioned above (and @nikita approved) Visual's methods accessing *private*, *internal*, *protected* doesn't work very well and makes *Visual Studio* crash. That's why I have to find another way to access private properties. nikita suggests to use reflection. Can you propose some template for *Unit Tests* with all the required attributes and reflection mechanism?

Comment: I experienced this bug too in my own project. Both projects have 1 thing in common. Both contain a class with a generic type T and then another class derived from it. It seems private accessors fail to handle such a situation.